# Как вызвать шаблонную функцию без указания шаблонного типа

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto sum(T (*F) (T, const T &), Args&&... args)
// -> decltype(F(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) // for 11
{
    return F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto func = [](int a, int const& b) { return a += b; };

    int i = 4;
    // sum<int>(func, i, 2); // так будет работать
    sum(func, i, 2); // но нужно, чтобы работало так
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `auto sum(T F, Args&&... args)` или проблема в конфликте с другими перезагрузками sum?

Comment: Но ваша функция принимает определенное количество аргументов, и тут неопределенное количество параметров шаблона никак не уместно

Comment: Лучше делать как сказано в комментарии выше

Comment: `sum(+func, i, 2);` - потому что `sum` принимает указатель на функцию

Comment: Chorkov, спасибо.... тупил очень долго, не видя очевидное.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, к-во параметров может меняться. Тем не менее - спасибо!!